# Which special characters, if used in <title> tags, will be visible in Google SERPs?

Tags: google-search, search-results, title

Seems like Google doesn't display some special characters if they are used in `<title></title>`. What are the characters that will be visible in SERPs for site titles?

Comment: From my experience, using letters, numbers and simple punctuation marks like dash, comma or dot is good. See [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suTDT6-Q8NE) from Matt Cutts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an article about icon characters](http://www.schreibe.org/en/special-characters/) and how they can be used so that your listing in the SERPs catches the eye.  It does appear to be somewhat out of date because I don't see many of characters in the SERPs anymore for the examples they have.

That isn't to say that it isn't possible.  When doing a research query for this question, I came across this listing which abuses special characters, probably through rich snippets:

[image]

One of the sites that was in the article appears to have found some icon characters that still work when used in title tags:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google SERPS will mostly like see all of your special characters. Although please remember each one takes up on character as does a letter and that could potentially take up the space needed in important keyword real estate.

Comment: While google sees the special characters, I have tested to find out that it doesn't display them. The ones like heart, square, etc... Instead of using such words as Free, Best, Must, Newest, sometimes it is better to show some fancy character to lure attention of searchers.