# Are HTML encoded symbols allowed in meta description?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-description

I am using HTML-encoded symbols like `&mdash;` or `&amp;` inside the meta description field. Will they be displayed properly by Google and other engines or should I correct the text to have only ASCII symbols?

Comment: Very similar to [Which special characters, if used in <title> tags, will be visible in Google SERPs?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63346/which-special-characters-if-used-in-title-tags-will-be-visible-in-google-ser)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are allowed in the meta description tag. They are valid HTML entities and will be handled and displayed correctly by search engines.